# Iterating over outlook emails very slow

Tags: powershell, outlook

Using COM access via PowerShell, I want to retrieve certain properties from Outlook folder items. The folder is a shared Exchange folder that has been synchronized in offline mode and outlook is put offline (should be no server access). I use this query, where $pt is MAPIFolder

```
$ol = new-object -comobject "Outlook.Application"
$mapi = $ol.getnamespace("mapi")
$inbox = $mapi.Folder /* skipped*/
$pt.items|select-object Subject, Sendername,  SentOn,Recipients,ConversationIndex,ConversationTopic,CC,Bcc,ReceivedTime|export-csv -path pentest.csv -noTypeInformation
```

The folder has a couple thousand entries and this query does not complete overnight and PowerShell+Outlook chew all CPU resources.  By obvserving the output pace, it appears to output a dozen entires then stall, then output, stall, *ad nausea*.

How to speed it up? My ultimate goal is to do import it into some kind of SQL, hence the export to CSV.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I copied the contents of the folder locally.

Comment: Did you do it manually because it was quicker? Or because it was impossible with Powershell?

Comment: I iterated over a shared folder. Poweshell or not doesn’t matter as I used outlook automation API and this is where drag was.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Yes the automation API is slow so that makes sense, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about querying the search index? It already contains most properties of all items, is quite fast, and knows how to work in idle/cpu-conserving mode. There's a simple API to query it and you can export your results to CSV or DB. Just a thought.

Comment: Outlook's indexing is quite selective - it doesn't index this specific folder for some reason :(

Comment: What's special about the folder? Perhaps you can explicitly include it.